# UI pattern for shared editing scope among selected elements?

Tags: forms, design-patterns, terminology, wpf

I'm having a hard time researching this pattern for WPF, partly because I'm not exactly sure of the *correct term for it.*

As best as I can describe it, here is how this editing pattern works:

> Given is a UI which has a container that contains zero or more child
>   elements, and allows the user to create a selection of zero or more of
>   these child elements.  Each of these child elements is a form editor. 
>   Each child element has the exact same controls.  When the user selects
>   two or more of these controls, changes within the editing controls of
>   one form are reflected within all selected forms.

Because my description sucks, here's an example I'll couch in terms of a windows form application.

---

Here's a `ListBox` with three copies of the same `UserControl`.  The selected `UserControl` is colored light blue

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKOdXm.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Editing text in the text box only enters text in the selected `UserControl`

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9Rv8o.png)</sup>

Now, select the two other `UserControls`

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv7f3w.png)</sup>

And edits apply to *both of the `UserControls`*

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn3BVI.png)</sup>

**What is the name of this pattern?**

And, if anybody can tell me if this pattern is implemented within the WPF framework and where to start my research, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Closest thing I can think of is multi-line editing like in an IDE, but it's not really the same

Comment: @BenBrocka: I swear I've seen this before.  I'm pretty sure it is the default behavior in forms designed in Access, but I haven't dabbled in that for years (luckily).

Answer (score 1):

It's basically group editing, or at least that's the name I know. Select a bunch of files on your Windows desktop, then hit F2. One of them will be selected and put into rename mode. Change its name and you'll see that the same name was applied to all your selected files, along with a serial number to keep them unique. If that's what you meant.